# Javascript/CSS background positioning/dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable

I'm working with this code:

```
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 125px; background: #fff; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #999; cursor: pointer;">
    <div style="width: 100%; background: url(IMAGE NAME) no-repeat; cursor: pointer; background-position: center; background-size: 170px; height: 125px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make it so the user can position their photo to exact point without having to save a copy of another image. I know you can make a draggable element that lets you drag the background, just unsure how.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You posted code for two divs and a question that's not clear. How does this get two upvotes in less than a minute?

Comment: The question is, how do I make it so I can drag the background position to where I'd like it. I thought it'd be simple to understand. Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable_parent" ).draggable();
  });
</script>
<div id="draggable_parent" style="width: 450px; height: 450px; background: #fff; -webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #999; cursor: pointer;">
  <div id="draggable" style="width: 184px; background: url(IMG_URL) no-repeat; cursor: pointer; background-position: center; border:1px solid; background-size: 170px; height: 125px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have edited the code, with the above code, the outer div will move.

Comment: Not exactly; im looking for a way to drag the background positioning.

Comment: So you want to move the parent div? I am sorry but I am just trying to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The background position for the first div, I would like to be able to move it by dragging.

Comment: No, i need to be able to move the background-position with dragging. And I have the jquery-ui lib.